# Picking characters of vector and randomly placing them in a matrix

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have a String[50] that contains 50 characters, those characters need to be placed in a String[10][10] using (int)(Math.random() * 3) so the loop would go through the entire matrix placing the characters in the last position+whatever math.random gets.
These questions that teachers ask that limits the way you can answer them drives me nuts.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a phrase.");
    String phrase = entrada.nextLine();
    while (frase.length() > 50) {
        System.out.println("The phrase has to be less than 50 characters. Try again.");
        phrase = entrada.nextLine();
    }
    int carac = phrase.length();
    String[] vector = new String[carac];
    for (int i = 0; i < carac; i++) {
        vector[i] = String.valueOf(phrase.charAt(i));
        System.out.print(vet[i]);
    }
    int position = 0;
    String[][] matrix = new String[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            position = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            matrix[i][j] = vet[i] //this part doesn't make any sense, I'm stuck here.
        }
    }
}
```

Example of desired output:

[image]

Comment: This is how I understand it. You need to keep a running total of lastPos + current random number and place the character in lastPos. But that means you need to compute the row and column for lastPos. If lastPos = 48, then row = 48/10 = 4 and c = 48%10 = 8. Also, the way you described it means you may overwrite some characters the random number just generated is 0.

Comment: You may want to discuss this with your teacher to get some clarification on what is expected based on the comments in this post.

Answer (score 1):

The image shows that the characters from the input string need to be randomly distributed in the matrix.

So, a step can be calculated "randomly" (initially from 0 to 2, then from 1 to 3), and position in the matrix can be recalculated using division `/` and modulo `%` operations

Also, with this implementation array `vet` seems to be redundant, and `vet[i]` may be replaced with `String.valueOf(phrase.charAt(i))`:

```java
int position = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < carac; i++) {
    int row = position / matrix.length;
    int col = position % matrix[row].length;
    matrix[row][col] = vet[i]; // or just String.valueOf(phrase.charAt(i))
    position += (int)(Math.random() * 3) + 1; // shift by 1 position is needed here!
}
```

Then the matrix could be printed:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + ": ");
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print((matrix[i][j] == null ? " " : matrix[i][j]));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Sample output (with shift):

```
0:  TE  S T  
1: I  N G  S 
2:  E NT  EN 
3: C E       
4:           
5:           
6:           
7:           
8:           
9:
```

**Update**  Sample output (*without* shift):

```java
0: TSTI G EN 
1: T NC E    
2:           
3:           
4:           
5:           
6:           
7:           
8:           
9:
```

It is evident that without the minimal shift of 1, lots of characters from `phrase` will get overwritten when put to the matrix and `position = 0`.

Comment: Why are you doing this? `position += 1 + random.nextInt(3);` That is not what the OP said to do.  Just add the `random number*3`  And you should stick with `Math.random()` since that is what the OP used and this is clearly an assignment.

Comment: `(int)(Math.random() * 3)` may return 0 and therefore the position won't be shifted.

Comment: Exactly.  And the OP didn't say to do that.  So overwriting an existing position may happen.  Here is a direct quote *last position+whatever math.random gets.* A lot of details were missing.

Comment: The array `vet` is what contains the text to be distributed in the matrix, if there is no `vet` there is no text and the final output is blank. Plus I need to use `Math.random()` because reasons. Im just starting to learn and the teacher asked to do this assignment but he didn't explained anything even close to this so Im completely lost.

Comment: @Wanderer, in the original code there are several issues related to incorrect variable names: 1) `while (frase.length() > 50)`  -- should be `phrase`, no `frase` is declared; 2) same with `vet` -- `vector` is declared, `vet` is missing. Also, expected output clearly demonstrates that there's always a minimal shift of 1.

Comment: @Wanderer, I provided the "update" using `Math.random` and without the shift.  The sample output with 0 shift is provided too so that you could compare them (how the characters may overwrite each other).

Comment: Also, the sample image shows that the difference between two characters may be 3 as in `T--E` in words TESTING and SENTENCE and even 4 as in `S---E` - this is not feasible with `(int)(Math.random()*3)` which provides random values in closed range `[0..2]`